# Looking for a sci-fi book about children being raised by androids with names related to literature

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a science fiction book where the last children on Earth were raised by androids, who they thought were human. The children had literary names like Charlotte Bronte.

Comment: [Related, could it be this one?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/74096/story-about-a-young-girl-raised-created-by-robots)

Comment: The title says that the androids had literary names, but the body of the question says the children have literary names.

Comment: Please see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info or https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question on how you could improve your question so that there's a greater change we can find the book, and edit your question.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59647/book-about-shakespeare-and-churchill-as-a-robot (which does not have an accepted answer)

Answer (score 3):

This is [The Overman Culture](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?255933) by Edmund Cooper.

The main character is a boy named Michael Faraday.

> Michael's best friends were Horatio Nelson, Ernest Rutherford, Jane
> Austen and Emily Bronte.